# use dynamic component in the nuxt layout get runtime compile error

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

in my nuxt application. in layout file use dynamic component for set the component in different pages like below

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="app-body">
      <div id="app-topbar">
         <component v-bind:is="actionBar.component"></component>
      </div>

      <div id="app-content">
        <nuxt />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

but when I'm runing the application I got the error in below

```
You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.
```

I'll try to wrap my `component` in `no-ssr` tags but the error still exist

Comment: Why dont you just use the compiler-included build of Vue as suggested in the error message?

Comment: can you give me a document link about it?

Comment: Sure, here are the [official docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only).

Comment: I read this before but I need to config this in nuxt. can you give any link to config this on the nuxt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as DigitalDrifter already said, you need to use the compiler-included build.

To do that in nuxt try to add the following to your nuxt.config.js:

```
build: {
  extend(config, ctx) {
    config.resolve.alias['vue'] = 'vue/dist/vue.common'
```